# How to find two randoms nodes with no edges between them in graph?

Tags: python, networkx

I am quite new in python, I want to find two random nodes in network which has no edges between them, But my program sometimes return empty list or more than two nodes.
can anyone help me on this, My program is:

```
import networkx as nx
import random
n=6  
m=10
G=nx.gnm_random_graph( n, m, seed=None, directed=True)
result = []
nodes = random.sample(G.nodes(), 2)
for u in nodes:
    for v in nodes:
        if u != v and G.has_edge(u,v) is False and G.has_edge(v,u) is  False:
        result.append((u,v))
    else:
        nodes = random.sample(G.nodes(), 2)
 print(result)
```

Comment: A warning: it may be worth checking that the graph isn't complete.

Comment: Also, if the graph is not directed, there's no need to check whether `(v,u)` is an edge after checking `(u,v)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx
import random
n=6  
m=10
G=nx.gnm_random_graph( n, m, seed=None, directed=True)
nodes = G.nodes()

def select_2_random_unconnected_nodes(node_list, graph):

    selected_node = random.choice(node_list)

    # obtain all the nodes connected to the selected node
    connected_nodes = [n for _, n in G.edges(selected_node)]

    print(connected_nodes + [selected_node])

    # a feasible node is one not in connected_nodes and also not the first selected_node
    feasible_nodes = [feasible_n for feasible_n in node_list if feasible_n not in connected_nodes + [selected_node]]

    # select a second node from the feasible_nodes list
    select_second_node = random.choice(feasible_nodes)

    return selected_node, select_second_node
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, it was very helpful.

Comment: No problem. You should accept the above answer though. Clearly superior to mine.

Comment: I tried above code using igraph instead of networkx, now node_list is node_list = graph.vs() and connected_nodes = [n for _, n in (G.es.select(_source=selected_node) and G.es.select(_target=selected_node))] But gives back self-loops and multiple edges between nodes, do you know how it works in igraph/python?

Comment: I meant, I used those unconnected nodes and add one edge between them.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want one pair of nodes, there is no reason to make a list. Just find the pair!

```
while True:
    u, v = random.sample(G.nodes(), 2)
    if not (G.has_edge(u, v) or G.has_edge(v, u)):
        break
```

Now use `u` and `v` directly.